# Does the concept of an 'Islamic Name' have authentic origin?

Tags: halal-haram, naming

Does such a concept have an authentic origin in the Islamic faith? i.e. is there any restraints or regulation on how one should name a their child?

I don't see how this relates to the teachings of Islam as when the companions of the prophet reverted to Islam they were not asked to change their name.

Comment: It is truly cultural and shouldn't have any real relations to the teachings of Islam, however I was actually pretty chocked when I got to know that in Morocco for instance, you cannot name your children whatever name you want. It had to be an islamic name or arabic at least (or hebrew for jews only). Recently they started accepting berber names though.

Comment: @Kilise I think this was the case in Iran as well, not sure. I do agree that this is completely cultural, the biggest give away is that people often refer to any Arabic name as an Islamic name.

Comment: There are recommendations. Like naming a child a name thar has a good meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no hard and fast rules in Islam for naming. But **Prophet (صلي الله عليه وسلم)** has said about naming children with decent names and names which have good meaning.

There is a **Hadith** in the book **Sunan Abi Dawood, Hadith # 4950** which goes like this.

> قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ: تَسَمَّوْا بِأَسْمَاءِ الْأَنْبِيَاءِ، وَأَحَبُّ الْأَسْمَاءِ إِلَى اللَّهِ عَبْدُ اللَّهِ، وَعَبْدُ الرَّحْمَنِ، وَأَصْدَقُهَا حَارِثٌ، وَهَمَّامٌ، وَأَقْبَحُهَا حَرْبٌ وَمُرَّةُ
>
> **Translation:**
>
> The **Prophet (صلي الله عليه وسلم)** said: Name by the names of Anbiya (Prophets), and the most liked names by Allah (جل جلاله) are Abdullah and Abdur Rahman, and the most True names are Haris and Hammam and the most disgusting names are Harb and Murrah.

In another **Hadith** in the same book,  **Hadith # 4948** it is said that

**On the day of judgement, you will be called by your names and the names of your fathers. So Name (yourselves and your children) with decent names.**
This hadith is as follows:

> قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ: إِنَّكُمْ تُدْعَوْنَ يَوْمَ الْقِيَامَةِ بِأَسْمَائِكُمْ، وَأَسْمَاءِ آبَائِكُمْ، فَأَحْسِنُوا أَسْمَاءَكُمْ
>
> **الله ورسوله أعلم**